# Prevent dragging and dropping text selections between inputs

Tags: html, css

I have tested this in latest chrome and IE11.

It is possible to select a text in an input, and then drag it to another input, in at least IE11 and chrome.

And I want to prevent this.

I have found lots of examples/tutorials showing how to prevent the opposite in examples on how to implement drag and drop: Allowing drag, while preventing text selection.

But I want to allow text selection on mouse drag - but prevent the selected text to be draggable.

Setting the css property -webkit-user-drag: none; also prevents text selection, where I would have expected that the property: -webkit-user-select: auto; would control the prevention of text selection.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9g419erc/

```css
input {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  user-select: auto;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write text, select it, and drag">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Then drop text here">
</article>
```

A solution using css3 only is preferred

Comment: Check my answer. Hope it helps you. If you find it suitable kindly accpet it as answer. Thanks

Comment: A solution using css3 only is preferred, but thanks it is a smart solution that I did not think of.

Comment: 'll see if I can find any solution using css3

Answer (score 7):

Add `ondrop="return false;"` to those elements where you want to disable dropping text.

```css
input {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  user-select: auto;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Write text, select it, and drag" >
  <input type="text" placeholder="Then drop text here" ondrop="return false;">
</article>
```