# How to avoid text drag and drop inside contenteditable <p> JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, paragraph

I need to avoid drag and drop text inside content editable `<p>` My sample HTML code as follows,My content editable `<p>` have separate `<span>` as follows.

```
<div class="row">
  <p id="" class="given" contenteditable="true"><span>Lorem</span> <span>trst</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>Lorem</span> <span>Lorem</span> </p>
</div>
```

You can see in this image, I can select text and drag and drop it inside to another place, I need to avoid that draggable option. [image]

I saw several post regarding on this,

[Disable drag and drop of selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633149/disable-drag-and-drop-of-selected-text)

[How can I prevent text/element selection with cursor drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429827/how-can-i-prevent-text-element-selection-with-cursor-drag)

I need to do this using jQuery. How can I do it

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Use `dragstart`. The `dragstart` event is fired when the user starts dragging an element or text selection.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.given').on('dragstart',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); //disable cut,copy,paste
    console.log('dragable disabled !!');
  });
});
```